# How can I edit my intellisense setting on my vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, settings, intellisense

I am using vscode for my html project.

It has many helpful functions, but one of my best is intellisense ( I am actually not sure about it's name. 
but I have a little problem on it. How can I edit some settings of it

Because I am just supposing it's intellisense and not perfectly sure about what it is, first I will tell you what extension I've installed. 
I have "auto close tag", "beautify", "code runner", "python-autopep8".
and when I open my html file, type ! and press tab, then these DOCTYPE, head, body, blah blah, so many tag are typed. I mean completed. 
And what I want to do is change the contents of auto completion.

first I thought it "was auto close tag" but I can't find settings about that.

when I use that thing( type ! and press tab )
It goes like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and I wanna delete that second and third meta tags.
what can I do? and for further questions is that intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

That sort of options will usually be under **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings**.

In that menu you can then filter and find specific options relating to the extensions you have installed. Support for altering intellisense behaviour may or may not have been implemented.